# No column name was specified for column 1 of 'sp'

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have following query:

```
SELECT s."Description",
sp.*
FROM "Supplier" as s
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT p."Id", p."Description", p."Price"
    FROM "Products" as p
    WHERE p."SupplierId" = s."Id"
    FOR JSON auto 
) as sp
```

I'm trying to build json array according to `OUTER APPLY` result but I stuck here because there is an error `No column name was specified for column 1 of 'sp'.` I found similar question here on stackoverflow, but there is no example with outer apply.

Can you explain me what is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add a column alias to your applied result `sp`, e.g. `sp(json)`:

```sql
SELECT 
    s."Description",
    sp.*
FROM "Supplier" as s
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT p."Id", p."Description", p."Price"
    FROM "Products" as p
    WHERE p."SupplierId" = s."Id"
    FOR JSON auto 
) as sp(json) -- <-- Added alias
```

You can then access this in your overall results as either `sp.*` or `sp.json`, since the column is now named.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!